# Promise.resolve() returns a weird result when in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, promise

1.

```
let f = Promise.resolve(15);
console.log(f);

f.then(v => console.log(v));
```

Result:

```
[object Promise] { ... }
15
```

Everything works perfectly as thought ... but when I plug it inside a setTimeout() function I am not able to reason why the result is `1` ...

2.

```
let f = Promise.resolve(setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve(15), 1000));
console.log(f);

f.then(v => console.log(v));
```

Result:

```
[object Promise] { ... }

1
```

Thanks!

Comment: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) returns an <integer> reference that can be passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout. The reference would appear to be `1` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` does nothing with the return value of the callback function you pass it. Putting a resolved promise there is entirely irrelevant.

The resolved value of the outer promise is the return value of `setTimeout`.

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
>   passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

---

If you want to resolve a promise after some time then use a normal promise constructor.

```js
const promise = new Promise(
    (res) => {
        const resolve = () => res(15);
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }
);

promise.then( value => console.log(value) );
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing returned is the `setTimeout`'s `timeoutID`, a number assigned by the browser to track all the separate `setTimeout` calls.

The mistake you're making is here:

```
let f = Promise.resolve(setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve(15), 1000));
```

You're creating a `Promise` that instantly resolves using `Promise.resolve` and making it instantly resolve with `setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve(15), 1000)`. This is probably the first timeout within the script, which is why the `timeoutID` is `1`.

You want the promise to resolve with `15`, not `setTimeout[...]`. What you should do to achieve the result you're aiming for is this:

```
let f = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(15), 1000));
```

That is, create a new `Promise` that starts a new `setTimeout` which runs after 1000ms and resolves the containing `Promise`.